# Kotlin: How to change background color of the toggle button?

Tags: kotlin, togglebutton

I hope to change the background of the Toggle Button.
There would be two ways, in xml and in code, I think..

[image]

I have made using xml like this, successfuly;

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="Download"
            android:textOn="Downloaded"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg_sector"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

toggle_bg_sector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_download"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_downloaded"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

toggle_download.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
</shape>
```

toggle_downloaded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/gray" />
</shape>
```

It works very well..
However, I want to know to make this Programmatically.

I made this inside of the onCreate.

```
downloadButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _: CompoundButton?, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked)
                downloadButton.setBackground(R.drawable.toggle_download)
            else
                downloadButton.setBackground(R.drawable.toggle_downloaded)
        }
```

However, I got and error message on the `R.drawable.toggle_download`.

[image]

Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also change the color in MainActivity like This

```
downloadButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _: CompoundButton?, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked)
            downloadButton.setBackground(R.drawable.red)
        else
             downloadButton.setBackground(R.drawable.blue)
    }
```

In this way you can easily change the background color of toggle button

Comment: hi mate, then do I need to set a drawable resource?

Comment: Thanks mate, anyway I will close the question. :)